# resize using ffmpeg in python syntax error

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to resize a video using ffmpeg in python but am having an error with the syntax.  I would expect it to be as easy as this (which is my code)

```
import ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i video.mov -vf "scale=250:150" newmovie.mp4
```

this gives an invalid syntax of this:

```
    ffmpeg -i video.mov -vf "scale=250:150" newmovie.mp4
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -vf scale=250:150 newmovie.mp4
```

and also putting everything file in quotations.  No luck.

Comment: That's a shell command, not a Python statement.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation of the `ffmpeg` Python module to see the proper way to use it?

Comment: No my mistake I thought it was a python command.  It comes up in all the python searches as the way to use it.  @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Barmar wisely pointed out this is a shell command NOTa python command.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -vf "scale=250:150" newmovie.mp4
```

Correct documentation for python is found here:

```
https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`ffmpeg`](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) in Python, here's the code wrapped up in a function:

```
def vid_resize(vid_path, output_path, width, overwrite = False):
    '''
    use ffmpeg to resize the input video to the width given, keeping aspect ratio
    '''
    if not( os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(output_path))):
        raise ValueError(f'output_path directory does not exists: {os.path.dirname(output_path)}')

    if os.path.isfile(output_path) and not overwrite:
        warnings.warn(f'{output_path} already exists but overwrite switch is False, nothing done.')
        return None

    input_vid = ffmpeg.input(vid_path)
    vid = (
        input_vid
        .filter('scale', width, -1)
        .output(output_path)
        .overwrite_output()
        .run()
    )
    return output_path
```

so for your example just do:

```
newmovie_path = vid_resize("video.mov", output_path = "newmovie.mp4", width = 250)
```